# write audio to memorystream from file

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm trying to send this file to the outputstream but cannot figure out why it spits out basically an empty mp3 file. As you can see I would get an exception closing the stream prematurely so I have commented out for now. Any pointers appreciated.

```
using (FileStream mp3file = File.OpenRead(newFile))
                {
                    context.Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
                    context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[mp3file.Length];
                    memStream.SetLength(mp3file.Length);
                    mp3file.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mp3file.Length);
                    memStream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)mp3file.Length);
                    //mp3file.Close();
                    memStream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                    //memStream.Close();

                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is the problem:

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[mp3file.Length];
 ...
 // Here you're reading into the memory stream buffer...
 mp3file.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mp3file.Length);
 // And here you're overwriting it with the byte array full of zeroes!
 memStream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)mp3file.Length);
```

You shouldn't *assuming* that a single call to `Read` will actually read everything anyway though. It's not clear which version of .NET you're using, but if you're using .NET 4 or higher, you can use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd782932.aspx) to make it simpler.

It's *also* unclear why you're using a `MemoryStream` at all. Why don't you just copy straight to the output stream?

```
mp3File.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Or if you're using an older version of .NET:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024]; // For exmaple...
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = mp3File.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

(This is pretty much the equivalent of `CopyTo`.)

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that if I removed `memStream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)mp3file.Length);` that it would work but no dics. This is .net 4. Being one for efficient code and a noob to .net I'm a little confused trying to implement your suggestions. Here's what I tried: `byte[] bytes = new byte[mp3file.Length];
                        mp3file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)mp3file.Length);
                        mp3file.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);` an no joy. I really am trying to get this myself and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MrBrimm: Well at that point you've already *read* all the data - so `CopyTo` won't help. Why bother reading it into `bytes` at all? *Just* use `CopyTo`? Also, if you're having problems and you're relatively new to .NET, *stop* trying to micro-optimize. Write clear code first. When you're absolutely confident in your code, the language and the platform *then* you can optimize if you really must.

Comment: these files are less than 10k. I tried this and empty file again `using (FileStream mp3file = File.OpenRead(newFile))
                    {
                        context.Response.AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
                        context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
                        mp3file.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                    }`

Comment: Turns out that this did work. I was having build issues which were driving me nuts. I restarted VS and boom. Thanks!