# Byte Array to Audio in browser

Tags: c#, html, audio

I have .wav files on the server and a service that returns me a `byte[]`.  Right now I have following code to push .pdf and image files in a new window and it works great:

```
Context.Response.Buffer = false;
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Context.Response.Flush();
```

So I tried to simply change the ContentType to `audio/vnd.wav` and that DOES pop up the Windows Media Player.  However I get the message "Windows Media Player cannot play the file.  The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."  However, if I play the file from the store where I get the bytes, it plays in WMP.

Is there something special I need to do since it is an audio file?  I have looked around here and the web and have not found a recent useful answer.  The backend is C# .Net 4 (Not MVC) and I can use HTML5 controls (desired but not required.)  Since it is in its own popup window where I do the above code, it is not really tied to ASP.Net on the UI side.  Would hope I could just stream the bytes to an `<audio>` tag instead of the `src` attribute being a file name.

**UPDATE**
I did notice in WMP that once it seems like it is ready to play, a message in the player says "Media changing."

Comment: look at this previously asked question.. also if it doesn't help you.. then do a google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243672/write-audio-to-memorystream-from-file

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I did do a google search (which I mentioned.)  Your link assumes I can not get the bytes.  I can get the bytes, all of them.  Just seems like there is either a Header I am missing or it is trying to play the audio before it is totally loaded?